# Need help to Countdown in javascript and PHP

Tags: javascript, countdown

I encounter a worry in my countdown which does not show me anything. The page (index.php = require ('countdown.php');) only reloads and I do not understand why.

Can you please help me out?

countdown.php

```
<span id="Hour"></span><span id="Mins"></span><span id="Secs"></span>
<script>
function refreshCountdown()
{
  $.ajax({
    url: 'chrono.php',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'JSON'
  }).done(function(resp) {
    if (resp.status) {

if(resp.Hour > 9) {$('#Hour').html("" + resp.Hour + ":");} else {$('#Hour').html("0" + resp.Hour + ":");}
if(resp.Mins > 9) {$('#Mins').html("" + resp.Mins + ":");} else {$('#Mins').html("0" + resp.Mins + ":");}
if(resp.Secs > 9) {$('#Secs').html("" + resp.Secs)      ;} else {$('#Secs').html("0" + resp.Secs)      ;}

    }
    else {
       window.location.reload();
    }
  });
}
$(function() {
    setInterval(refreshCountdown, 1000);
});
</script>
```

chrono.php

```
<?php
$countdown = strtotime("10:10");
$diff = $countdown - time();
$ret = new stdClass;
$ret->status = false;

if ($diff > 0) {
  $ret->Hour = (int)($diff / 3600);
  $diff -= $ret->Hour * 3600;
  $ret->Mins = (int)($diff / 60);
  $ret->Secs = ($diff - $ret->Mins * 60);
  $ret->status = true;
}

die(json_encode($ret));
?>
```

Comment: It's almost certainly because `$diff` is negative. so the code in your if statements doesn't execute. `$diff` will be negative if `$countdown` is in the past- which it is for me- `$countdown` is 10:10am and it's past 7pm right now. You need to put a bit more thought and work into how you create the 'target' time for the countdown.

Comment: The time that I put is fictitious, it must normally be superior at the moment.
In fact, every Wednesday for example at 10:10 am here, the countdown tale counts until arrived at 00:00:00 and a redirection is done.
Only the countdown is invisible and the page refreshes every second ... it does not display the chrono...